# How to append CSV file into dbf?

Tags: append, visual-foxpro

Do you know how to append a .csv file into DBF by using FoxPro command , instead of using import wizard?

I have tried the code below, but it is not working.

Code:

```
Append from getfile() Delimited With ,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use append from:

```
local lcFileName
lcFilename = getfile()

if !empty(m.lcFileName)
  append from (m.lcFileName) type delimited
endif
```

This would do appending including the header line. However, if you have a field that is not character, then you could use it to skip header line. For example say there is a column named theDate of type date and should not be empty, then you could say:

```
  append from (m.lcFileName) type delimited for !empty(theDate)
```

Or if you are appending into an empty cursor, you could say - ... for recno()>1.